# Standard reference for a fundamental theorem on classification of root lattices

Tags: reference-request, integer-lattices, root-systems

In Schuett-Shioda's *Mordell-Weil Lattices*, the authors refer to a fundamental theorem on root lattices:

> **Theorem 2.25** Any positive-definite even integral root lattice is isometric to an orthogonal sum of root lattices of type $A_n$, $D_k$ and $E_\ell$.

Since they mention it so briefly, it seems like this is so well-known that barely needs mention.

But what would be a standard/classical reference for this theorem?

Comment: You can probably find the general result on the classification of root systems in most textbooks on Lie algebras. For example the one by Brian Hall or Humphreys. The result you quoted here is a special case, presumably because of the restriction to *even* integral lattices.

Comment: @ElliotYu, thanks for the references. There's something I'm not getting right about the definitions. In Schuett & Shioda's terms, a lattice $L$ is _even_ and _positive-definite_ if $\langle x,x\rangle$ is a positive even number for all $x\neq 0$ in $L$. Wouldn't that include $B_3$, for example?

Comment: I don't think so. $B_3$ also includes the norm-$1$ roots $(\pm 1, 0, 0), (0, \pm 1, 0), (0, 0, \pm 1)$, so all integral vectors are in the lattice. The situation with $C_n$ is a bit different, because the $C_n$ and the $D_n$ root *lattices* are the same, but $C_n$ includes roots of the form $2e_i$, which are longer.

Comment: At a glance, it seems to me that Schuett and Shioda's definitions go in the opposite direction from the usual order of presentation, say in Lie algebra textbooks. Here they first define (1) integral lattices, then (2) even lattices, then (3) roots of even lattices, then (4) root lattices, finally they state that (5) even integral root lattices have an ADE classification.

Comment: This is all correct, I think, but since step (2) already restricts to a special case, in step (3) the definition is also a specialized one. Under this definition, even though $C_n$ and $D_n$ have the same root lattice, only the latter root system is generated.

Comment: @ElliotYu, I get it now. In Schutt-Shioda's notation, $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is assumed to be symetric from the start. But in Humphreys' book, $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle$ is by definition $\frac{2(\beta,\alpha)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is an inner product in $\Bbb{R}^n$. Therefore in Humphreys notation $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle=\langle\beta,\alpha\rangle$ if and only if $\alpha,\beta$ have the same lenght. Since there is no such symmetry for the roots in $B_n,C_n, F_4, G_2$, these are ruled out by Schuett-Shioda.

Comment: Ah I didn't consider the possibility that the notation $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ could mean something different... Hazards of just skimming "the relevant parts", I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw this in Ebelings book "Lattices and Codes". In Chapter 1, the classfication into types $A_n, B_n$ and $D_n$ is proven.

Comment: A very neat book, thank you